# RijndaelManaged returns empty result

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

**The Problem** 
I want to decrypt encrypted data with `RijndaelManaged` but the result is always empty (either `""` or an byte array with the length of the data full of zeros).

All parameters, salt and data are all correct, `CryptoHelper.CreateRijndaelManagedAES` gets called the exact same way in the encrypt method (which produces an good output).

The only thing left I could think of is that I use the streams wrong, but I can't figure out why ...

**Code**

```cs
public static RijndaelManaged CreateRijndaelManagedAES(byte[] passwordHash, byte[] salt)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    };

    // Derive a key of the full Argon2 string (contains also meta data)
    using Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordHash, salt, 10);
    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

    return aes;
}

public static async Task<string> EncryptDataAsync(string plainData, byte[] passwordHash, int saltSize)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Generate a random salt
        byte[] salt = CryptoHelper.GenerateRandomSalt(saltSize);

        // Write the salt unencrypted
        using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await memoryStream.WriteAsync(salt);

        // Encrypt the data and write the result to the stream
        using RijndaelManaged aes = CryptoHelper.CreateRijndaelManagedAES(passwordHash, salt);
        using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        await streamWriter.WriteAsync(plainData);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        return ENCRYPTED_MAGIC + Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    });
}

public static async Task<string> DecryptDataAsync(string encryptedData, byte[] passwordHash, int saltSize)
{
    if (!HasValidMagicBytes(encryptedData))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The given data isn't encrypted");
    }

    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        byte[] saltAndData = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData.Substring(ENCRYPTED_MAGIC.Length));
        byte[] salt = saltAndData.Take(saltSize).ToArray();
        byte[] data = saltAndData.TakeLast(saltAndData.Length - saltSize).ToArray();

        // Decrypt the data and return the result
        using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using RijndaelManaged aes = CryptoHelper.CreateRijndaelManagedAES(passwordHash, salt);
        using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
        return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    });
}
```

**Security Notice**
Don't use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with only 10 iterations (as I do) if you pass a password to it. I derive a key from the password beforehand due to performance reasons (Blazor WASM) and pass the result to the `CreateRijndaelManagedAES` function.
If you  want to use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with a password you should use at least 50000 iterations (as of 2020).

*Explantation*
The iterations parameter is basically a cost parameter. The higher the iterations count the harder it gets for an attacker to brute force the derived password (as he would need more computing power/time). [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) has made a [publication](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#sec5) in 2017 which it states that you should use as many iterations as your environment can handle but at least 10000. I can't find the source anymore but I remember to have read that you currently should use at least 50000 (due to future security).

Comment: I can' t reproduce the issue by substituting the missing functionalities with my own implementations. For a repro it would therefore be useful to post the _complete_ code including `CryptoHelper.CreateRijndaelManagedAES` and the encryption counterpart of `DecryptDataAsync`, see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "If you want to use Rfc2898DeriveBytes with a password you should use at least 50000 iterations (as of 2020)." - may I ask why?

Comment: @MatthewLayton I updated the question; does this answer your question or were you going somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the `EncryptDataAsync` method, i.e. the encryption (in `DecryptDataAsync`, i.e. the decryption, the bug only becomes evident). This is because the `StreamWriter` must first be flushed before `memoryStream.ToArray()` is called. This call must be executed *before*:

```
...
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(); 
...
```

that is:

```
...
streamWriter.Flush();
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock(); 
...
```

or alternatively

```
...
streamWriter.Close();
...
```

which flushes/closes *both* streams, see also [`StreamWriter.Flush()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush?view=netcore-3.1) and [`StreamWriter.Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.close?view=netcore-3.1).